# wso2 inline configuration of activemq jms failover transport

Tags: wso2, jms, activemq-classic, esb, failover

ActiveMQ's failover transport can be configured in the URI:
http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html

in a proxy service, you can use:

```
<address uri="jms:/MyQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?startupMaxReconnectAttempts=10&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
```

This works with one configuration parameter. However, I couldn't find a way to have multiple parameters. Let's say I also want to configure the timeout parameter. I tried:

```
<address uri="jms:/MyQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?startupMaxReconnectAttempts=10&amp;timeout=10&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
```

This doesn't work because the timeout parameter is not part of the provider.url parameter.

I also tried:

```
<address uri="jms:/MyQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?startupMaxReconnectAttempts=10;timeout=10&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
```

This doesn't work because activemq doesn't support using ';' instead of '&' as a separator

I then tried

```
<address uri="jms:/MyQueue?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=failover:(tcp://localhost:61616)?startupMaxReconnectAttempts=10%26timeout=10&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
```

This doesn't work because wso2 doesn't url-decode the provider.url parameter before passing it to activemq.

How can I pass multiple parameters in activeMQ's failover transport configuration URI ?

Comment: did you try &amp instead of a raw & to let the xml validate ?

Comment: In the examples I gave, I never used a raw &.